# RestEasy rest client format query parameters

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, query-string

I need to call a 3rd party rest service from my Java application with a formatted URI:

```
.../rest/v1/search?filter[first_name]=john&filter[last_name]=smith
```

The reason for this format is, that there are several query fields (20+) and I can't create a @QueryParam parameter for every fieldname.

```
@POST
@Path("/rest/v1/search")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response searchCustomer(@QueryParam("filter") Map<String, String> filter);
```

My example with a map results in

```
/rest/v1/search?filter={first_name=John,+last_name=Smith}
```

How do I achieve the URI form with square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Context UriInfo` to get a map of all the query params instead of hardcoding every param

example:

```
@POST
@Path("/rest/v1/search")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response searchCustomer(@Context UriInfo info){

  //here are some different ways you can use the uriinfo
  MultivaluedMap<String,String> map = info.getQueryParameters();
  String firstName = map.getFirst("filter");
  String lastName = map.getFirst("lastName");
}
```